# Manual beam with chord and single note in lilypond

Tags: chords, lilypond, beaming

I want to make a manual beam - on left side its a chord and to the right a single note.

[image]

What I tried was

```
<f''8 a''8> [c'8]
```

which gives :

> 'error: syntax error, unexpected UNSIGNED'

How to rectify this error.

One related question:
How to make manual beam between two chords?
Like

```
<f''8 a''8> [<c'8 d'8>]
```

I have consulted the Lilypond documentation on this:
http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/beams.en.html

Comment: This was actually <f'' a''>8 [c''8]. Got the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you should have the note value outside of the chord. i.e. `<f'' a''>8`

Both `[` and `]` should be placed after the note value of the note they are beaming i.e.  `<f'' a''>8[ c''8]`